# @KafkaListener separate filtering logic for each listener

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need to define a custom filtering strategy for each listener produced by the listener factory.
Currently, I'm using `RecordFilterStrategy` to do that:

```
@Bean
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryProject() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(new RecordFilterStrategy<String, GenericRecord>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> consumerRecord) {
          return true;
        }
    });
    return factory;
}
```

But such filtering applies to all listeners produced by this factory. What I need is something like to define the different logic for each listener:

```
@Component
@SendTo("out")
@KafkaListener(topics = "incoming")
public class TestListener {

    @Filter
    public boolean filter(){
        return true;
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public TestObject listener(TestObject testObject) {
        log.debug("Received Message: " + testObject);
        return testObject;
    }

}
```

Does spring-kafka have some tools to do that? Or I need to write such logic on my own?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't. What you just need is a set of `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` beans with particular `RecordFilterStrategy`. Then your `@KafkaListener` should just specify which factory they are based on:

```
/**
 * The bean name of the {@link org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory}
 * to use to create the message listener container responsible to serve this endpoint.
 * <p>If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any.
 * @return the container factory bean name.
 */
String containerFactory() default "";
```

Comment: The single filter could also change its logic based on the `record.topic()`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan @GaryRussell Thanks for the answers. But defining the new  `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` for each listener is not a very flexible mechanism for me. Actually, I found a way to define a separate filter for each listener, but it requires using the reflection mechanism and listener's id inside of the  `setContainerCustomizer` for each created message listener. Also, I don't know what consequences will be for such a straight forward way.